# Windows 10 Blue Screen (BSOD) SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION if left idle for a few minutes

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

My Windows 10 Pro computer has been fine for the past 5-6 months I have been using it. But the past few days, it **will get blue screen if left idle for a few minutes**.. I have tried updating all drivers I could find, update BIOS, scan hard drives etc but nothing works.. I even reset/downgrade some drivers to the original preinstalled versions but still getting blue screen..

I downloaded blue screen viewer from nirsoft, and it seems to have something to do with `ntoskrnl.exe`, whatever that is...

[image: Blue screen viewer]

In the even viewer, it says bugcheck 0x0000003b :

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000003b (0x00000000c0000005, 0xfffff801538eb9af, 0xffffd00026ebd720, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 1952b824-7580-4761-a1b1-8b35a74307ea.

Most forums says it has something to do with video driver (Intel HD Graphics 4600), I have updated my video driver to the latest but still the same..

**If anyone want to see the DMP file, here it is: [Minidumps](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=19E154F72FD38C97!114319&authkey=!AFy_T3wINPzACkQ&ithint=file%2C7z)**, I do not know how to open the file.

The computer is working fine without a single problem if I am using it, but **the moment I left it idle for a few minutes, it will get BSOD**... this is very annoying since I frequently left my computer idle every now and then...

Comment: the crashes happen while doing registry operations (nt!NtOpenKeyEx+0xf). Looks like the registry is damaged.

Comment: Possibly use process monitor to filter and log registry queries in hopes of identifying the key or the service? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into all technical, you can try these easy steps for a quick fix:

1. Disable screensaver and all power saving functions (like going to sleep after 15 mins) to eliminate problems caused by Windows entering S3/S4 sleep. If BSOD persists...
2. Try running this command in an elevated (as Administrator) command prompt to verify and repair damaged system files:

> sfc.exe /scannow

Hope one of them works.